# Json only being deserialized to one array object

Tags: c#, json, google-api, deserialization

I am trying to read from the Google Nearby Places API, but for some strange reason my array only contains one object of 20, when the json is deserialized.
If somebody to shed some light on this mystery, it would be very much appreciated.

This is the json data I am trying to deserialize:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CqQCEgEAAJaY2BXnovCpj_poiYe4xpYf3MeG7K8jDuWSXA0vLjUaEtJXdx02WMEwha-opqU3bu53Asqk-BNo1nkM3AxJboxNa_tPAgF2MBck2tYqoi4vT2b688K5P8uIc1R-pUK43JfbUiQbHXRbIFxITsqQr7eipqu8LOkmjB0YsUqLQGTk6qEFtAdpaaNpXCmwLOEbDH0zRIQ93Hh5rAixD-qYvUVpLydZirOUGnKttLCzxebsQUEuhRdegEsCTF9eerEKh4UKrcNUuIo-InNzl8eAwxKhfhuA7UbOF_qwEqvAw-0jd9ADvQxqFzGPtKlW8osIgQByRXGHo6my6w1fH7EfFdkyD7m4_7u8Gd8y1J6_FWysYO0jmZc4fORCau4sSMgGfRIQycDKwBteF23rIUfL-p2y6xoUviw5O-NvxBFVNUcyPs3MbTaNJFA",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.8709434,
               "lng" : 151.1903114
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8694072197085,
                  "lng" : 151.1917756802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8721051802915,
                  "lng" : 151.1890777197085
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "e644f7f34cf875b9919c6548f1b721947362850a",
         "name" : "Lunch Cruise with Jazz on Sydney Harbour",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 292,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105423912060796272053/photos\"\u003eLunch Cruise with Jazz on Sydney Harbour\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRYAAAAXZ_EwtUdHz9ygfjeYyDNJ0D_Bw3SNUw-Q3yXdpR-L5EyLGzdUQFOg5Ird7wppV50dCP8b2xtCmktAN5CcNBTYmhdojr3ZlMvNkiZTtLbM4cE9LhT7KHVekhuQX4tiAgfEhDta1eIaptCZfxoR8IJOWkjGhRJ2qeNNdYBXpmtizVlKL-1Ll9n6g",
               "width" : 438
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJLfySpTOuEmsRPCRKrzl8ZEY",
         "rating" : 3,
         "reference" : "CmRRAAAAwpe8CREsyzSI_-4MagTJIBrlb-MNxItMrcKWbmXD8TI4FnG7Akby3jUNJBXWTqW7urN0gl7p_uU0C9whyxrUJZWems2fA3IFo_ElO9ATI-kwoQXVQtlGTw04Zkg0yhmkEhB8R-cRUnyVWLd5lTPxrds_GhSyoVq8pEbViMmcVQjF0UaMomneMg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "night_club",
            "bar",
            "restaurant",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "37 Bank Street, Pyrmont"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.8671207,
               "lng" : 151.2016385
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8657717197085,
                  "lng" : 151.2029874802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8684696802915,
                  "lng" : 151.2002895197085
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "c620902a8565dd4c4d605fecbe4f9b585d881b62",
         "name" : "Blue Line Cruises",
         "place_id" : "ChIJvwSIiTiuEmsR8hEazPa4W7U",
         "reference" : "CmRSAAAAz7zMj99x1HjVK2qKp1Iki-tHYIV0Qz5J_PlvZD0cHks2-pD76D9IXBdWt4qnjdLT2wNzXdKqGeVCeS2oQNW4c00mZjew3oj-emo-fn3UoDV2SRniF2sl0bgSH6Q_cQH2EhC-qzspkhfyrzTNzY9QhBEuGhRqu9i_Ry22HiGYvK2uzhNJR35V4Q",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Australia"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.867591,
               "lng" : 151.201196
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.86624201970849,
                  "lng" : 151.2025449802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -33.86893998029149,
                  "lng" : 151.1998470197085
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "a97f9fb468bcd26b68a23072a55af82d4b325e0d",
         "name" : "Australian Cruise Group",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2448,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/118410684014024830328/photos\"\u003eMichael Mak\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRYAAAAEHtRlILy8HdDJAw3oa5jhMA4MIW9J9jYUYto_vCejzRoN9gEiGAq4GBpbAgwhtGPe7CjKX4jyRjrSVzJdbddhYhUj5SPPjqg5bA-hZt9NG1VAsgUktnHZPE3fq5wVw83EhBhf8PPHYin0FQwhKsQChNYGhSinnvfBU_rr7S1ab3z_-uBGrEYgQ",
               "width" : 3264
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0",
         "rating" : 4.8,
         "reference" : "CmRRAAAAc2nTxLrX_BmwqkhWxKYMNQpRmDLZlU-jgFyQOfTBAeUlnzOla4AU5ZUFL7US-t8NrwmgCIQYjSdvjNdLwsNjHQrrdQdSt8_q5VtGXBgNcQzL8eczkNUfeHcvXToGjTKkEhAyuauhQhfb9X7xmS64EJurGhSLDXCaOdtRBoK0YmavfC1picKF7w",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "travel_agency",
            "restaurant",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "32 The Promenade, King Street Wharf 5, Sydney"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.8677371,
               "lng" : 151.2016935
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8664006697085,
                  "lng" : 151.2029067302915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8690986302915,
                  "lng" : 151.2002087697085
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "ce4ffe228ab7ad49bb050defe68b3d28cc879c4a",
         "name" : "Sydney Showboats",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 900,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105231077511067622688/photos\"\u003eChristie and Matt Snapshots of Food\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRYAAAAV4f1akIe5Kbh3yAtZziLKGwPXvN9qMG7I4P76OXB1B51lLUb8brun6zm0bD70BFTah6WyMMVOBwf_BYPOGMk3rF92eFRLvJOyYxrYYxxpBM5UVLz14EvENJcoo78GzV1EhAGyejRsDjuub5kyV6IJEHfGhTk_f8dWrvIx6Li_dZv4g79wSw7Xg",
               "width" : 1600
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJjRuIiTiuEmsRCHhYnrWiSok",
         "rating" : 4.1,
         "reference" : "CmRSAAAAIUfa-ey-n8JeqIkg-QkqgFMwvWkXGituimgpD0kKC6r81MNFwGJHogWx4vRklKdStm1gZnKoriuugK-_gHK_oe2cmcyjtMvFlm79XVi3qP6UOKk47X6jA7NOaDu1WFedEhDbSLWPrkJw1y-YOKzB8NRPGhQ13Gq-m6OeKd1LDVICr6RC52VJMQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "travel_agency",
            "restaurant",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "32 The Promenade, Sydney"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.87104699999999,
               "lng" : 151.189736
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8693729197085,
                  "lng" : 151.1912852302915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8720708802915,
                  "lng" : 151.1885872697085
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "3458f23c154e574552e0722773a46f384816b241",
         "name" : "Vagabond Cruises",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1200,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101516907347198229066/photos\"\u003eVagabond Cruises\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRYAAAAUb14jHhngpxuAjTBfcJ0rYhmjD3lLr-sHhS8D72eHFyvqPi5SojeuxhUnNv8WXwxVCr_VCMKyqDCbVi6AGZqpbe5-ojbMNaD37MfJ4m37nA1cifP15Osw39WSSE7TtlAEhCu3TCrA_NPLTY3mCNdLyl2GhTlOgZGvQspx12wQGAHGNh26mEeEw",
               "width" : 1800
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJLfySpTOuEmsRMFymbMkVkOE",
         "rating" : 3.7,
         "reference" : "CmRSAAAAfBHUWq20M5YndE6MgHHiuhrzLGIfVhG4b0Y1zrYBJdzoFaKfMiDmF7aL-zfwY-NyLMQFdnzZKp0W2Nujydcy5g85rR3tCb1roR6UN8bmT0G1rRcZbCPTO0FNRK5Bax8fEhBLCo0bITmRBdPKu6lp0MbcGhTMBcikSVn6V30U3YJdeDL46bQY8Q",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "travel_agency",
            "restaurant",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "37 Bank Street, Pyrmont"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.8686058,
               "lng" : 151.2018206
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8673641197085,
                  "lng" : 151.2033695302915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8700620802915,
                  "lng" : 151.2006715697085
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "21a0b251c9b8392186142c798263e289fe45b4aa",
         "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 480,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104066891898402903288/photos\"\u003eRhythmboat Cruises\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRYAAAAQoKfbo8toSJdsHuy9BbYqRJDwbhvurNzkCIj65Dqnr_y14BgeqUP1WfL2fgD2BUWAzP_1fvbmTJdq5QsKF_Xzc1BPxQgBn9naW9eAH0J-LG8xSbnQ_CoXYlUmR1iXwSbEhDCNAse8BSTr_O7ztgDC9-BGhQMgDhAcIDY1TOJJyUXk8NAjLz8UA",
               "width" : 640
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
         "rating" : 3.6,
         "reference" : "CmRSAAAAVI_so0hyPbi2dP8iBDnQ9y_dDza42GhU_GZaOPyAFMehYP7QIEdlPAMkw1a1GE_s77uxsdnw7bhKl4djkQbK7dxnWaqvZl7XLr1CnaYQuf1VpH-HUMJW8Mc3dxig9OqVEhDo4LgQM7j87F1xQS2Ew73yGhSMNCUMLE5iL280CbVFZiJbczSWQA",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "travel_agency",
            "restaurant",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "King Street Wharf, King Street, Sydney"
      },        
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.86473759999999,
               "lng" : 151.2013113
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8633802697085,
                  "lng" : 151.2028230802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8660782302915,
                  "lng" : 151.2001251197085
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "3b915b9bd520e5fcd19b5ece8aa53d67765f2aea",
         "name" : "Banksii",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2988,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106372957228079765255/photos\"\u003eMohammad Khan\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRYAAAA9WKq8Zl2GF3A35KukQWzLWTMKdkDzgTz7lBEuJLP89KM0qmle62WMnfEX4f4LD2Q8LiwB50DQA-ydVRrjZIKBdZ-LFTdX2maheksT7VkEbNy_yODjhiIEaUiRycuDm3cEhCJTY3QUHiULJMivayKVFboGhT9NMVFT9RD3jGDCRToc8DLDbPH0Q",
               "width" : 5312
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJgXD2qEeuEmsR0jnXdMoFBMo",
         "rating" : 4.1,
         "reference" : "CmRSAAAAzwPCIjY0nVJtdEkbZ48282l3UekXlPu2QAnl7MHddh_zykB-HKuodk9hjilgGvBg9sWxxgMWURJKHXg5Hg8vPB2abMhcRgucvpnstsnH0HHwO1imUeDpOixGUqbjHUWiEhA_FyaNqXpXOD_mxhqHqVUoGhTJXMte2rMzk3h3BR9-QS-EMiJmLg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "33 Barangaroo Avenue, Barangaroo"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I've both tried to use json2csharp and many other things, but to no success.
The first item is deserialized perfectly, but only one result is stored in the results array. Here is my deserialization class:

```
class NearbyPlaceAPI
{
    public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
    public string next_page_token { get; set; }
    public Result[] results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
public class Location
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Northeast
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Southwest
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Viewport
{
    public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
    public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
}

public class OpeningHours
{
    public bool open_now { get; set; }
    public List<object> weekday_text { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public int height { get; set; }
    public List<string> html_attributions { get; set; }
    public string photo_reference { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public OpeningHours opening_hours { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
    public string vicinity { get; set; }
    public int? price_level { get; set; }
}
```

To deserialize my json I have the following code:

```
var NearbyPlaceAPIurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=MYKEY";
var jsondata = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(NearbyPlaceAPIurl);

NearbyPlaceAPI PlaceAPIResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NearbyPlaceAPI>(jsondata);
```

To me it all looks correct and everything is deserialized perfect, except it only deserializes one of the results objects and i end up with one object in my results array.

Thanks

Comment: The code you've given works fine for me with the JSON you've got - if I print `result.results.Length` it prints 7. Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem. (I was loading the JSON directly from disk - I suggest you provide a sample that does the same. It's also worth reducing the sample JSON to a minimal example demonstrating the problem.)

Comment: Thank you Jon. PlaceAPIResult.results.Length returns 1 for me.
I will try to provide a better example.

Comment: That suggests the JSON you're getting isn't the JSON in your question. Try the JSON that's in your question, loading it from disk

Comment: I just loaded it through a file and it read it perfectly. That is very strange.

Comment: It seems like the api returns something different to my webclient, than my browser. When i call the api through the webclient, it only presents 1 item, but 20 in chrome. Thanks for your suggestions Jon!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
public List<Result> results { get; set; }
```

instead of 
      `public Result[] results { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes, i did. Unfortunately it doesn't return any results, if i use a list instead of array.